# Somar variavel sempre que for chamada

Tags: php

bom entao gostaria de saber se ha alguma forma em PHP para fazer o seguinte, definir uma variavel ex: $contatorinicio = "0"; e depois sempre que chamar ela no php ela ir somando mais um EX: $contadornovo = $contador + "'"; porem cada vez que eu usar um echo sair o resultado somado em sequencia EX:

```
<?php $contador = "0";
   $contadornovo = $contador++;
```

---

```
<a href="#menu<? echo $contadornovo"; ?>" >produtos</a>
<a href="#menu<? echo $contadornovo"; ?>" >fotos</a>
```

no caso seria imprimido assim

```
<a href="#menu1" >produtos</a>
<a href="#menu2" >foto</a>
```

con javascript ate consegui mais seria possivel isso no php puro?

O usuario @rray me deu a dica e funcionou assim da seguinte forma

```
<?php $contador = "0"; ?>
<?php echo ++$contador; ?> // imprime 1
<?php echo ++$contador; ?> // imprime 2
<?php echo ++$contador; ?> // imprime 3
```

Comment: Anderson não entendi, pelo que eu li aparentemente você mostrou o que queria fazer.

Comment: Chamar ela no PHP de que forma?

Comment: Pode fazer `++$contadornovo;`

Comment: como o modelo abaixo, cada vez que eu chamar ela $contadornovo ele continuar somando +1 EX: 1ª vez $contadornovo = 1 $contadornovo = 2 $contadornovo = 3 entendeu?

Comment: @rray o resultado foi o mesmo ficou 1 1

Comment: @JulioHenrique97 atualizei o post com exemplo

Comment: Tentou [assim](https://ideone.com/qL94Yu) ?

Comment: deu certo sim tinha arrumado com o nome errado  <?php $contador = "0"; ?>
     <?php echo ++$contador; ?>
        <?php echo ++$contador; ?>
               <?php echo ++$contador; ?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta uma variável - [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/2icH7G)

```
$contador = 0;

echo '<a href="#menu'.++$contador .'">produtos</a>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<a href="#menu'.++$contador .'">fotos</a>'. PHP_EOL;
```

Conforme comentário  `<id="1"> <a href="1">`  [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/Pg26gF)

```
$contador = 0;

echo '<div id="'.++$contador .'"><a href="#menu'.$contador .'">produtos</a></div>'. PHP_EOL;
echo '<div id="'.++$contador .'"><a href="#menu'.$contador .'">fotos</a></div>'. PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: sim sim era isso mesmo , mais aki uma outra duvida tem como  exibir o mesmo resultado 2x antes de pular pro proximo pq meu codigo esta assim <id="1"> <a href="1"> seu seu chamar <id="++$contador"> <a href="++$contador"> vai ficar <id="1"> <a href="2"> isso e possivel, fazer o contador dar o resultado 2x?

Comment: o que gostaria de saber era se era possivel apenas usando uma variavel e é sim alterei seu codigo deu certo https://ideone.com/ljhpWu   << apenas chamar a variavel sem o + ela dara o resultado anterior ja somada, de toda maneira deu bom

Answer (score 1):

sugestão:

```
$opcoes = ["proutos", "fotos"];
foreach($opcoes as $id => $opcao){
    echo '<a id="'.++$id.'" href="#menu'.$id.'">'.$opcao.'</a>';
}
```

vc tem o mesmo resultado entretanto fica mais escalavel e melhor para manutenção